# Mustache partial notation in Eclipse / Zend Studio 10 throws invalid character warning

Tags: eclipse, mustache, zend-studio, mustache.php

I'm running Zend Studio 10 with code using mustache templating.  Mustache notation for including a partial is (from https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#partials):

```
{{> my/partial}}
```

This triggers a syntax warning (a little yellow triangle with exclamation point).

```
Invalid character used in text string
```

Has any else experienced this in Zend Studio with any templating languages?  How did you go about adding an exception to code checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell:

1. The html Validator is triggering the error
2. There is no mustache validator for Eclipse
3. There isn't an easy way via Eclipse preferences to add a rule like `allow/ignore {{>` to a validator--namely the HTML validator

My current solution is to disable the HTML validator on mustache files by adding an exclusion group to the validation settings to ignore anything `.mustache`.

This sucks however since I'd really like to validate 99% of the code that's non-mustache HTML in these files with the build in validator :(